# Import self made Python module from outside serverless folder

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a serverless folder with a Python AWS Lambda Function in it. I want to *include* a module from *outside* of the serverless folder. This is my folder structure:

```
projectRepo/
├── serverless/
│   ├── serverless.yml
│   ├── handler.py
├── src/
│   ├── main.py
└── └── utils/
      ├── __init__.py # from .myModule import *
      └── myModule.py
```

I have added `sys.path.append(..\src\utils)` in `handler.py` and this works locally. However, when triggering `handler.py` lambda in AWS I get: `No module named 'utils'`

Is there a way I can import `myModule.py` into `handler.py` and still leave it where it is now?

Comment: General quick trick: `sys.path.append`. But in your case `utils` is not a valid package because it lacks init file. Read this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages (there's also some info on `sys.path.append` in there)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. This is a lambda served by Serverless Framework. I can run `handler.py` locally, but when triggering the lambda manually in AWS I get `No module named 'utils'`.

Answer (score 3):

Add (empty) `__init__.py` files in the `serverless`, `src` and `projectRepo` folders. Then, you can use the `from projectRepo.src.utils import whatever_functions` in `handler.py`, provided you are running your code with `projectRepo` as working directory (unless you actually add a package setup to install your code as a package, e.g. in a local virtual environment).

Comment: Are you sure this will work for uploading python lambdas with serverless framework? Can't get this to work. Files are probably not stored in the folder sent to the aws lambda

Comment: What I suggested is the usual way of making internal imports within a Python package (which, if run from the right working directory, does not require installation to be used). That being said, I have no idea how AWS works, and am unsure about what you mean by lambdas (actual `lambda x: x * 2` style objects, or something else?). It might be worth it to turn your code into an installable package (with a `setup.py` file), so that you can install it in your AWS instance and run it there.

Comment: Yeah I'm talking about AWS Lambdas. I guess a `setup.py` is the best option. Thank you.